# A function to return the path of a tree structure

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I am having trouble coding this up, basically what I needed to do is for any node with a tree structure, I want to return the path that it took, please see code

```
class Node {

    let value: String

    var parentNode: Node?
    var childenNode = [Node]()

    func appendNode(node: Node) {
        childenNode.append(node)
        node.parentNode = self.parentNode
    }

    func path(node: Node? = nil) -> (CeilingTypes, [ModuleTypes]) {

        let node = node ?? self

        let ceilTitle: CeilingTypes
        let moduleTitle: [ModuleTypes] 

        // immplementation 

        return (ceilTitle, moduleTitle)

    }

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Was trying to do a `for...in` loop because realized that I can't treat this like an array. For clarity, the `ceilingTypes` is the first level of the tree and `moduleTypes` are all the children which stems from `ceilingTypes`

For example, if the tree structure is this:

```
                                  [Main]
                         /                      \
                  [Ceiling_1]                [Ceiling_2]
                /            \              /           \
        [Module_A]      [Module_B]   [Module_C]  [Module_D]
```

If I run `path(Module_A)` the return should give me `[Main, [Ceiling_1]]`

Relationship between  `Ceilingtypes` and `ModuleTypes`, they are both `enum`s

```
enum CeilingTypes {
    case KWIKLOC_REGAL
    case KWIKLOC_PREMIUM
    case KWIKLOC_CORPORATE
}

enum ModuleTypes {
    case _1200X600_REGULAR_H_PATTERN
    case _1200X1200
    case _600X600
    case _600X600_HEAVY_DUTY
    case _1200X1200MM
}
```

And here is the tree structure

```
struct MenuStructure {

    static var structure: Node {

        // All nodes
        // First layour nodes

        let mainMenu = Node(value: "Select Ceiling Type")
        let KWIKLOC_REGAL = Node(value: "KWIKLOC Regal 24mm Alum. T-bar")
        let KWIKLOC_PREMIUM = Node(value: "KWIKLOC Premium 15mm Alum. T-bar")
        let KWIKLOC_CORPORATE = Node(value: "KWIKLOC Corporate 32mm Mitred Top Hat")


        // Second layour nodes

        let _1200X600_REGULAR_H_PATTERN = Node(value: "1200 X 600 Regular H Pattern")  
        let _1200X1200 = Node(value: "1200 X 1200")
        let _600X600 = Node(value: "600 X 600")
        let _600X600_HEAVY_DUTY = Node(value: "600 X 600 Heavy Duty (Main Tees at 600 Centers)")
        let _1200X1200MM = Node(value: "1200 X 1200 mm")

        // First layour - connections

        mainMenu.appendNode(node: KWIKLOC_REGAL)
        mainMenu.appendNode(node: KWIKLOC_PREMIUM)
        mainMenu.appendNode(node: KWIKLOC_CORPORATE)

        // Second layour - connections

        KWIKLOC_REGAL.appendNode(node: _1200X600_REGULAR_H_PATTERN)
        KWIKLOC_REGAL.appendNode(node: _1200X1200)
        KWIKLOC_REGAL.appendNode(node: _600X600)
        KWIKLOC_REGAL.appendNode(node: _600X600_HEAVY_DUTY)

        KWIKLOC_PREMIUM.appendNode(node: _1200X600_REGULAR_H_PATTERN)
        KWIKLOC_PREMIUM.appendNode(node: _1200X1200)
        KWIKLOC_PREMIUM.appendNode(node: _600X600)
        KWIKLOC_PREMIUM.appendNode(node: _600X600_HEAVY_DUTY)

        KWIKLOC_CORPORATE.appendNode(node: _1200X1200MM)
        return mainMenu

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not at all clear what the relationship of these CeilingTypes and ModulesTypes are to your Node class.

Comment: Sorry, please see edit

Comment: I see the edit, but the `Node` class still doesn't have these as instance members. Is that what they're supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, I've added in the tree structure, is there anything I can add to make it more clear? thanks

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how a tree works. In this example, you have a tree of `String`s, but you're somehow trying to pull enumerated types out of it. I'd suggest looking into recursive functions. The general case is to use a recursive function to climb up the tree to find each parent `Node`, and add them to a returned `Array`. The signature of this recursive function might look something like: `func path(node: Node?, path: [Node]) -> [Node]`. You'd then use your newly minted Array of `Node`s to extract the information you seek.